# React shows unfinished elements before the page renders completely

Tags: reactjs

I am making a posts project with React. Whenever My home page just consists a bunch of posts in cards view. If I click on a certain card, it should navigate me to that post with some details. However, before the page renders completely, I still see some lines or 'unfinished' elements so to speak.

[This is what I see before the post and it's description render completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6fby.png)

How can I fix this?

Here is my JS file with posts:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import './Posts.css'

export class Posts extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.posts.map(post => (
                    <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} key={post._id}>
                        <Card key={post._id} className="shadow-sm">
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={post.image} />
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title id="cardtitle">{post.title}</Card.Title>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is the Post detail:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import { Media } from "react-bootstrap";

import './Post.css'

function Post({ match }) {
    const [post, setPost] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPost = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(`${POST_URL}${match.params.id}`);
            setPost(res.data);
        }
        fetchPost();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    const POST_URL = `/api/v1/posts/`;

    return (
        <Media>
            <img className="align-self-center mr-3 postImage" src={post.image} alt={post.title} />
            <Media.Body>
                <h5 className="postTitle text-center">{post.title}</h5>
                <p>{post.description}</p>
            </Media.Body>
        </Media>
    )
}

export default Post
```

Comment: You need code in your question.

Comment: @MisterSirCode Sorry, forgot about that.

Comment: maybe you are rendering some HTML before the data comes back from the API request

Comment: @MauricioAvendaño You are most likely right, because I just removed the data (received from my api) that is rendered on the details page, and the only thing I see are the lines and the border, just like the time before loading the DOM completely. How to fix it?

Comment: This is exactly what's happening, your HTML is rendering first before your API returns data and then re-renders once the data is set to internal state. If you don't want to show anything try `return post && <Media> ... </Media>` so you only render once you have data.

Comment: I fixed it guys thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function inside your component that conditionally render if the data has returned from the API. Something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import { Media } from "react-bootstrap";

import './Post.css'

function Post({ match }) {
    const [post, setPost] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPost = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get(`${POST_URL}${match.params.id}`);
            setPost(res.data);
        }
        fetchPost();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    const POST_URL = `/api/v1/posts/`;

    const renderPost = () => {
       if (post) {
           return(
             <Media>
            <img className="align-self-center mr-3 postImage" src={post.image} alt={post.title} />
            <Media.Body>
                <h5 className="postTitle text-center">{post.title}</h5>
                <p>{post.description}</p>
            </Media.Body>
        </Media>
              );
       }
     return <h1>Loading</h1>;
    }

    return (
       renderPost();
    )
}

export default Post
```

I recommend you to render a spinner or a placeholder to improve the user experience while the data is loading.

Comment: Sorry, Looks like I still see the containers of div except the Loading heading. I followed the code you provided.

Comment: Never mind I fixed it by setting the false as paranthesis on useState(). Which means I now have const [post, setPost] = useState(false); instead of const [post, setPost] = useState({});

Comment: My bad I did not see that you were initializing the state with an empty object, if you let [post, setPost] = useState(); should works too.